# Using Proguard with AIR SDK Mobile

Tags: android, actionscript-3, air, proguard, flashdevelop

I'm using FlashDevelop as IDE to create Air mobile apps, but have not encountered and seen any documentation or article pertaining to enabling or setting up Proguard with AIR SDK.

Generally APKs in Flex/Air SDK are created by running the bat files generated along with the creation of a project. Apparently, you don't see any build.xml or properties file.

Comment: ProGuard is for Java-based apps, not Air/AS3.

Comment: Not exactly. I just found a 2013 article BUT it is with flash builder and just part of the tutorial. http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/articles/android-licensing-native-extensions.html (scroll down to the "Tips for securing your application")

Comment: I was looking for more of a straightforward and simple documentation/process.

Comment: Ahhh, that is regarding the Android licensing libraries which are Java-based, you are not `ProGuarding` the generated SWC (AS3), just the included Java JAR/classes which are embedded in an ANE in order to obfuscate your Google Play license

Comment: Ok thanks, that made things clear.